# How to load self hosted mp3 files on click in React Player

Tags: reactjs, load, buffer, mp3, media-player

I use 16 React Players on my site and imported 16 different mp3 files. I´m worried about the loading time, so I thought it might be a good solution, if the mp3 file is only loaded, when the play button is clicked. Is this possible and can anyone give me a hint how to achieve this?

This is the beginning of the code from my Home.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/Badge';
import mp3_file from '../assets/music/mein_ahnenland_peru_maintheme_titel_torben_jan_mueller.mp3';
import action from '../assets/music/99firefilm2018_torben_jan_mueller_16bit_48khz_v3m_action.mp3';
import adventure from '../assets/music/schmonz_ep2_goldgraeber3_torben_jan_mueller_ueberarbeitet_n_cut.mp3';
import animation from '../assets/music/revolution_radio_torben_jan_mueller_16bit_48khz_final_m.mp3';
import comedy from '../assets/music/99firefilm2018_torben_jan_mueller_16bit_48khz_v3m.mp3';
import doku from '../assets/music/mein_ahnenland_peru_maintheme_titel_torben_jan_mueller.mp3';
import drama from '../assets/music/mein_ahnenland_peru_umweltzerstoerung_torben_jan_mueller.mp3';
import erotic from '../assets/music/02- Carefree.mp3';
import fantasy from '../assets/music/logo_jugendfoerderung_torben_jan_mueller_16bit_48khz_v8_final_master.mp3';
import horror from '../assets/music/13- Searching For Their Friends.mp3';
import lovemovie from '../assets/music/mein_ahnenland_peru_wiedersehen2_torben_jan_mueller.mp3';
import music from '../assets/music/daughterly_trailer_strings.mp3';
import other from '../assets/music/wodka_gorbatschow_plakadiva_torben_jan_mueller_16bit_48khz_v2m.mp3';
import sciencefiction from '../assets/music/block701_crowdfunding_halfbeat_atmo_torben_jan_mueller_16bit_48khz_n.mp3';
import western from '../assets/music/italowestern_suite_torben_jan_mueller_16bit_48khz_vintage1.mp3';

export const Home = () => (
    
            <div className="flex-container">

                <div>
                    <div className="adventure genreHeight">
                        <div className="genreBackground">
                            <h4>Adventure <Badge variant="success">New</Badge></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div className="playerBottom">
                            <ReactAudioPlayer
                                src={adventure}
                                controls
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>&copy; <a href="https://pixabay.com/de/users/thommas68-2571842/?utm_source=link-attribution&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=image&amp;utm_content=2202910" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Iván Tamás</a> - <a href="https://pixabay.com/de/?utm_source=link-attribution&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_campaign=image&amp;utm_content=2202910" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Pixabay</a></p>
                </div>
```

And finally a screenshot of the page:

[image: Screenshot of page with 16 React Players]

Answer (score 0):

After I read this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) I found the solution: You just have to add this line

> preload="none"

to each player instance and the audio file is only loaded, when you press the play button.

You can check the result with the Google Chrome dev tools. Go to Network, enable "Disable cache" and reload the page. As you can see in this screenshot, there´s no mp3 file preloaded.

[image: Google Chrome dev tools Network]

This is, how the player looks:

```
<div>
  <ReactAudioPlayer
     src={mp3_file}
     controls
     preload="none"
  />
</div>
```